# The last day of month with a given time flow in SAS

Tags: sas

I am bothered with a simple question.
I need to get the last business day of the month and the date in my dataset only includes the business day.

For example:

```
ID   Date
1    20180301
1    20180302
1    20180305
...
1    20180329
1    20180330
1    20180402
...
2    20180301
2    20180302
2    20180305
```

And I need the output like this:

```
ID   Date       Enddate
1    20180301   20180330 (The last business of March)
1    20180302   20180330
1    20180305   20180330
...
1    20180329   20180330
1    20180330   20180330
1    20180402   20180430 (The last business of March)
...
2    20180301   20180330 (Same for other IDs)
2    20180302   20180330
2    20180305   20180330
```

I tried to use this command:

```
enddt=intnx('month',date,0,'E');
```

However, it will output 20180331 instead of 20180330.

So I was wondering if there is a method to extract directly the last day of given month instead of the calendar month.

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: something like intnx('weekday',intnx('month','01mar2018'd,0,'e'),0); see this link https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/sas-sql-last-business-day-of-the-month/td-p/284973

Comment: Do you need to account for custom holidays? If so, you have to first develop your own calendar and then account for that. There is demo code in the SAS documentation on setting up a custom calendar and using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a data step:

```
1) sort on date from latest to earliest (reverse sort)
2) create a variable based on the yearmonth = int(date/100)
3) do a datastep by yearmonth and retain enddate
4) if first.yearmonth then enddate = date;
5) drop vars you don't want
6) sort back to original order
```

Comment: Hi DCR, thank you a lot for answering my question! I just tried:enddt=intnx('weekday',intnx('month',date,0,'e'),0); and thanks to your hints, it works!

Comment: that's great! up voting or accepting the answer would be nice too :)